# Ruby - Capture method calls sent from method body

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am looking for ways to ensure that a set of methods defined in my objects are all calling a particular method. To illustrate, say I have objects A and B, both have methods like so:

```
class A
  def method_a
     important_method!
  end
end

class B
  def method_b
     important_method!
  end
end
```

How can I easily ensure that both `method_a` from A and `method_b` are calling `important_method!`?

In this case `important_method` will come from a module that will be included in both A and B (Actually in their common superclass).

So far what I tried is to wrap both objects in a proxy that defines `method_missing` and collect methods calls, but this only tells me that `method_a` and `method_b` are called. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to verify that ruby works? If you are calling `important_method!` it will get called.

Comment: Ah right! I want to do it statically, so looping over all descendants of a particular class and see if their methods are calling `important_method!`.

Comment: For my particular use case its not feasible to simply call them because the methods do more than simply call `important_method!`. Plus these classes are added all the time, so I wanted to automated the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer was initially to use `TracePoint`, but then I read how @user2074840 used `alias`, which got me thinking of using `alias` in conjunctions with `caller`, which leads to a very direct solution. I present that below as `#2 Use Caller`.

**#1 Use TracePoint**

In Ruby 2.0+ you can use [TracePoint](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html) to obtain the information you need. (In earlier versions, you may be able to use [Kernel#set_trace_point](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func).)

To see how this works, let's lay down some sample code:

```
def a
  puts "a"
  c
  important
end

def b
  puts "b"
  important
end

def c
  puts "c"
end

def important
  puts "important"
end
```

We now set up for the trace, specifying the two events of interest, `:call` and `:return`, and the information we want to save, the event (`:call` or `:return`) and the method (`:a`, `:b` or `:c`):

```
events = []
trace = TracePoint.trace(:call, :return) { |tp|
  events <<  { event: tp.event, method: tp.method_id } }
```

Then execute the code:

```
4.times { send([:a, :b, :c][rand(0..2)]) }
  # b
  # important
  # b
  # important
  # a
  # c
  # important
  # c
```

disable trace:

```
trace.disable
```

and examine the information collected:

```
p events
  # [{:event=>:call,   :method=>:b},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:important},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:important},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:b},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:b},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:important},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:important},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:b},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:a},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:c},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:c},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:important},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:important},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:a},
  #  {:event=>:call,   :method=>:c},
  #  {:event=>:return, :method=>:c}]
```

Note that this cannot be run in `IRB` or `PRY`.

We can now extract the calls to `:important` as follows:

```
def calls_to_method(events, method) 
  stack = []
  events.each_with_object([]) do |h, calling_methods|
    stack << h
    while stack.size > 1 &&
          stack[-1][:event] == :return &&
          stack[-2][:event] == :call &&
          stack[-1][:method] == stack[-2][:method] do
      if (stack.size > 2 && (stack[-1][:method] == method))
        calling_methods << stack[-3][:method]
      end
      stack.pop
      stack.pop
    end  
  end
end

calls = calls_to_method(events, :important)
  #=> [:b, :b, :a]

calls.uniq
  #=> [:b, :a]
```

**#2 Use Caller**

This approach uses `alias` and [Kernel#caller](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller):

```
@calling_methods = []
alias :old_important :important

def important
  @calling_methods << caller.first[/`(.*)'/,1]
  old_important
end

4.times { send([:a, :b, :c][rand(0..2)]) }
  # b
  # important
  # c
  # a
  # c
  # important
  # a
  # c
  # important
  # b
  # a
  # a

p @calling_methods
  #=> ["b", "a", "a"]
```

Here's an example of an array returned by `caller`:

```
caller
  #=> ["abc.rb:9:in `b'",
  #    "abc.rb:32:in `block in <main>'",
  #    "abc.rb:32:in `times'",
  #    "abc.rb:32:in `<main>'"]
```

It is only the first element that we use:

```
caller.first
  #=> "abc.rb:9:in `b'",
```

and we apply the regex to extract the method name, which is preceded by `'`'` (Ascii 96) and followed by a single quote.

Comment: This is very good. Here is a follow up question: What would you do if the methods a,b,c raise exceptions that you are not interested in at the time you are checking for `important_method`? Imagine I want to this at program start, so whatever the programmer put in methods a,b, and c should not matter to my checker script, so ideally i want to ignore all exceptions. I understand this might be tricky though.

Comment: What I did now, since I am not interested in any exceptions, is to simply rescue from StandardError, but it's tricky because unless a call to `important_method!` is at the top of the method, I could rescue from the exception and never make it to that check.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. You must first fix the code that raises the exceptions. If you catch an exception and continue, you obviously may miss calls to `imporant_method` that would have been made had the exception not been raised.

Comment: Yep, in this case I will have to move to a more static solution that does not require me to run the code, otherwise I write a lot of code simply to ensure that there are no exceptions. Your answers however given my initial requirements are spot on. :)

Comment: One simple thing you might consider is writing a bit of code to look through the source listing, searching for calls to the given method. Often that would be indeterminent, of course, but if a method had no calls to the given method under any circumstances, you could rule it out. Alas, I don't know enough about your problem to know if that would have any merit.

Comment: I think it does yes. I know exactly which classes *should* have all public methods calling `important_method!`, and I know where they will be (say in folder A), so my plan now is to read folder A files, parse the ruby code in there, and ensure public methods are calling `important_method!`. The issue now is whether I should simply get the sexp and find def calls or what?

Comment: I you would like to analyse this statically you probably can use SexpProcessor or something. 
https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser
https://github.com/seattlerb/sexp_processor

I can try to do something. I was playing lately with those tools.

Comment: I've created once this
https://gist.github.com/michal-samluk/8e17f0f820c459f4426d
If you run it against your code it will visualise you the sexp tree. You can easilly see there that you have methods. You should have no trouble in creating a similar code that ensures the method call is within other method. This is static solution.

Comment: @michal.samluk, that's interesting. I'd think the OP would find that useful. After posting my last comment it occurred to me that I was probably suggesting the reinvention of the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I've played a little with this. What do you think about such solution?

```
module CallImportantMethod

  def important_method!
    puts 'Important Method called!'
  end 

  def self.included(base)


    base.instance_methods(false).each do |method_name|

      base.class_eval do
        alias_method :"old_#{method_name}", method_name 
      end

      base.class_eval <<-eoruby
        def #{method_name}(*args, &block)
          important_method!
          old_#{method_name}(*args, &block)
        end
      eoruby

    end 
  end

end 

class SomeClass

  def testing 
    puts 'My Method was called'
  end 

  def testing_with_args(a,b)
    puts a + b
  end 

  def testing_with_block
    yield
  end 

  include CallImportantMethod

end 

i = SomeClass.new 
i.testing 
# => Important Method called!
# => My Method was called
i.testing_with_args(5,8)
# => Important Method called!
# => 13
i.testing_with_block { puts 'passing block...' } 
# => Important Method called!
# => passing block...
```